# If Cell is X then Value of the Cell to its right will be Y, across entire column in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi I am new to VBA and am having trouble finding the solution to what I'm trying to do.

I have 2 columns

Lvl1 Lvl2
A - - X
A - - X
A - - X
B - - X

If Lvl2 is "X", then I want it to be replaced by the same value as Lvl1. So from first to third row, Lvl2 would be "A", and in row 4 Lvl2 would be "B".

Another way of seeing this woud be if Lvl1 is A, then Lvl2's text would be A as well. If Lvl1 is B, then Lvl2's text would be B, etc.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, why not just copy column `A` into column `B` -- sounds like that is all you are doing...

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, even if you are new to VBA, post what code you have tried. Second, *f Lvl1 is A, then Lvl2's text would be A as well. If Lvl1 is B, then Lvl2's text would be B, etc* means column lvl2 is **exactly** the same than column 1, so just copy and paste, or use a formula like `=A1` and dragdown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will get you started -

1. Loop through your rows. Here it is 2 to 4, when implementing, you will want to create a dynamic loop (`For i = 2 to LastRow`). How to do that is well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)
2. Check if the value in `Column B = X` - If so, give `Column B` the value from `Column A`

---

```
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i as Long

For i = 2 to 5
    If ws.Range("B" & i) = "X" Then
        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    End If
End if
```